# Using an interface for mocking purposes in unit tests for Java with Spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I have a problem trying to mock interfaces in my API based on Spring. I am getting this error:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in bm.app.services.Service required a bean of type 'bm.app.services.DiscountProvider' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'bm.app.services.DiscountProvider' in your configuration.
```

And I just don't understand it. I am adding an interface (DiscountProvider) as a parameter for a constructor of my service class (Service) in order to use Mockito for testing purposes.

The beginning of my Service (I think the only relevant part here) looks like this:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class Service {

    DiscountProvider discountProvider;

    public Service(DiscountProvider discountProvider) {
        this.discountProvider = discountProvider;
    }
```

The interface looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Component
public interface DiscountProvider {

    BigDecimal getThePriceOfTheProduct();
}
```

And my test class looks like that:

```
@Component
public class ServiceTests {

    Service service;
    DiscountProvider discountProvider;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should return the value higher by ten percent.")
    void shouldReturnValueHigherByTenPercent() {
        //given
        Mockito.when(discountProvider.getThePriceOfTheProduct()).thenReturn(new BigDecimal("20.00"));
        AdditionalMiniProduct product = new AdditionalMiniProduct(UUID.randomUUID(), new BigDecimal("300.00"), "Yellow Loan");
        //when
        BigDecimal result = service.increaseByGivenAmount(product.getNetPrice(), discountProvider.getThePriceOfTheProduct());
        //then
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo("315.00");
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturnACorrectRiskLevelValue() {
        int months = 18;
        assertEquals(5, calculateRiskLevelByNumberOfMonths(months));
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturnACorrectEnumValueBasedOnNumberOfMonths() {
        int months = 26;
        assertEquals(RiskLevel.HIGH, giveTheRiskNameBasedOnNumberOfMonths(months));
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturnAPriceOfAProvidedFinancialProduct() {
        BigDecimal productPrice = new BigDecimal(1200);
        String productName = "SilverLoan";
        assertEquals(productPrice,findAProductPriceByGivenName(productName));
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        service = new Service(discountProvider);
        discountProvider = Mockito.mock(DiscountProvider.class);
    }


}
```

Now, I am fairly new to testing, so I do expect to have made some rookie mistakes. The thing is, that's my first attempt to have more "complex" unit tests run with one of my Spring apps and I just don't get it. It refuses to acknowledge the @Component (or any other I managed to find) annotation.

Comment: Either make it fully springy, then you need to read something like https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing or you do not care about spring in the test at all and drop the `@Component` completely - that would make more sense for a unit test since there is nothing spring can and should do for you here. That being said you should certainly switch the two statements in `setUp` around, you first need to create the mocks and then use them.

Comment: Thanks, the switching of statements in setUp helped, but I also had to wrap the parameter with an Optional (Like this: public Service(Optional<DiscountProvider> discountProvider) {
        discountProvider.ifPresent(discountProvider1 -> {this.discountProvider = discountProvider1;});
    }). It compiles now without an error, but my method to select records from the database which was not connected to the issue stopped working at all and Postman bombards me with 500... but thanks again, this actually helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unit testing your `Service` class, you should mock all external dependencies of this class under test.

Assuming you are using JUnit 5, a possible test setup can look like the following

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private DiscountProvider discountProvider;

  @InjectMocks
  private Service service;

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Should return the value higher by ten percent.")
  void shouldReturnValueHigherByTenPercent() {
    //given
    Mockito.when(discountProvider.getThePriceOfTheProduct()).thenReturn(new BigDecimal("20.00"));
    AdditionalMiniProduct product = new AdditionalMiniProduct(UUID.randomUUID(), new BigDecimal("300.00"), "Yellow Loan");
     
    //when
    BigDecimal result = service.increaseByGivenAmount(product.getNetPrice(), discountProvider.getThePriceOfTheProduct());

    //then
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo("315.00");
  }

}
```

In addition, you don't need `@Component` for your test classes. This annotation is used for your *production* code to mark Spring beans.